# Modeling unknown # of Departments/Sections in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acl9

In Ruby on Rails, how can you model a situation where an `Employee` may belong to a `Section` and that `Section` **may or may not** belong to another `Section` all the way up to `Organization`. I am looking for a set of models that can handle an unknown number of levels. And then finding out the most immediate level an `Employee` is in, and each `Section` would have it's own admin(s).

I hope to use acl9 for authorization, but still can't figure out how this would be done if the number of levels is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Honestly, there were a few times where both answers were helpful and so I didn't choose either. I am still pretty new to this site and programming, so I didn't know proper protocol. Any other advice you can give about asking/responding to questions?

Comment: Like, if I find multiple answers helpful, is it good to up-vote anything that's helpful? Or is that considered...cheap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) sounds like it might do what you are looking for. There's a railscast on it as well: http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

Comment: Seems like a great place to start. Thanks!